# Is there a way to pass a lambda function to reference the dataframe in a dictionary comprehension?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, dictionary-comprehension

I'm trying to emulate the behavior of R's `mutate(across())` with `Pandas`, and a one-liner way of doing it is through dictionary comprehensions. For example, if I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```py
df.head()

>>>            jam_cpi_eop  bah_cpi_eop
>>> 1980-01-01       3.038       38.714
>>> 1981-01-01       3.183       42.193
>>> 1982-01-01       3.406       44.115
>>> 1983-01-01       3.974       45.653
>>> 1984-01-01       5.212       47.748
```

And I want to take the `np.log()` of `jam_cpi_eop` and `bah_cpi_eop` columns of my DataFrame in only one go, I can write the following code:

```py
df1 = df.assign(
        **{f'l{col.name}': np.log(col) for col in [df.jam_cpi_eop, df.bah_cpi_eop]}
    )

df1.head()
>>>             jam_cpi_eop    bah_cpi_eop  ljam_cpi_eop    lbah_cpi_eop
>>> 1980-01-01        3.038         38.714      1.111199        3.656201
>>> 1981-01-01        3.183         42.193      1.157824        3.742254
>>> 1982-01-01        3.406         44.115      1.225539        3.786800
>>> 1983-01-01        3.974         45.653      1.379773        3.821069
>>> 1984-01-01        5.212         47.748      1.650964        3.865937
```

The problem is that if I need to make more operations on the newly created columns `ljam_cpi_eop` and `lbah_cpi_eop`, I can't use `df` as a reference anymore. Is there a way to pass a lambda function to the list inside the dictionary comprehension?

I would expect something like the following lines, but it doesn't work.

```py
### DOESN'T WORK!
df1 = df.assign(
        **{f'l{col.name}': np.log(col) for col in [lambda x: x.jam_cpi_eop, x.bah_cpi_eop]})
```

EDIT:

What I need is to take the differences of the logs in a second step. For example, the following code works:

```py
df1 = df.assign(
        **{f'd{col.name}': col - col.shift(1) for col in [df.jam_cpi_eop, df.bah_cpi_eop]})
```

But I want to take the difference of the log variables that I created in the first step, and not of the original columns.

I know that I can do it by assigning an intermediate dataframe, but I'm interested in knowing if there's a way to do it without creating an intermediate DataFrame.

Comment: how would you run this with mutate .. across in dplyr?

Comment: `df %>%
  mutate(across(c(jam_cpi_eop, bah_cpi_eop), ~log(.x), .names='l{.col}')) %>%
  mutate(across(c(ljam_cpi_eop, lbah_cpi_eop), ~.x - lag(.x), .names='d{.col}'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to pass a lambda function to the list inside the dictionary comprehension?

One way to achieve this is using [`DataFrame.pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html)

```
df = (df
 .pipe(lambda x: x.assign(**{f'l{col.name}': np.log(col) for col in [x.jam_cpi_eop, x.bah_cpi_eop]}))
 .pipe(lambda x: x.assign(**{f'l{col.name}': col - col.shift(1) for col in [x.ljam_cpi_eop, x.lbah_cpi_eop]}))
)
```

Result:

```
              jam_cpi_eop  bah_cpi_eop  ljam_cpi_eop  lbah_cpi_eop  lljam_cpi_eop  llbah_cpi_eop
1980-01-01        3.038       38.714      1.111199      3.656201            NaN            NaN
1981-01-01        3.183       42.193      1.157824      3.742254       0.046625       0.086053
1982-01-01        3.406       44.115      1.225539      3.786800       0.067714       0.044546
1983-01-01        3.974       45.653      1.379773      3.821069       0.154235       0.034269
1984-01-01        5.212       47.748      1.650964      3.865937       0.271191       0.044868
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a loop, simply apply the vectorial operation:

```
df1_log = np.log(df1)
```

output:

```
            jam_cpi_eop  bah_cpi_eop
1980-01-01     1.111199     3.656201
1981-01-01     1.157824     3.742254
1982-01-01     1.225539     3.786800
1983-01-01     1.379773     3.821069
1984-01-01     1.650964     3.865937
```

to merge both dataframes:

```
df1_combined = df1.join(np.log(df1).add_prefix('l'))
```

output:

```
            jam_cpi_eop  bah_cpi_eop  ljam_cpi_eop  lbah_cpi_eop
1980-01-01        3.038       38.714      1.111199      3.656201
1981-01-01        3.183       42.193      1.157824      3.742254
1982-01-01        3.406       44.115      1.225539      3.786800
1983-01-01        3.974       45.653      1.379773      3.821069
1984-01-01        5.212       47.748      1.650964      3.865937
```

##### if you have other columns you do not want to affect:

```
# columns on which to apply the transform
cols = ['jam_cpi_eop', 'bah_cpi_eop']

# apply transform on subset and combine
df1_combined = df1.join(np.log(df1[cols]).add_prefix('l'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this is a toy example. In my DataFrame, I have many more columns and I want to keep the original columns next to the transformed columns, and then take the difference of the logs without discarding them.

Comment: Then just subset the columns on which to apply the transform: `np.log(df1[[(jam_cpi_eop', 'bah_cpi_eop']])`

Comment: @JoaoPedroMacalos I updated the answer with an explicit example

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works, but what I really need is to take the difference of the log-transformed columns in a second transformation, which is not so straightforward. I updated my question to highlight this point.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting it up makes it cleaner;  I feel you are stretching the mutate across syntax (that's my personal opinion):

```py
step1 = df.pipe(np.log).add_prefix('l')
step2 = step1.sub(step1.shift()).add_prefix('d')
df.assign(**step1, **step2)
 
            jam_cpi_eop  bah_cpi_eop  ljam_cpi_eop  lbah_cpi_eop  dljam_cpi_eop  dlbah_cpi_eop
1980-01-01        3.038       38.714      1.111199      3.656201            NaN            NaN
1981-01-01        3.183       42.193      1.157824      3.742254       0.046625       0.086053
1982-01-01        3.406       44.115      1.225539      3.786800       0.067714       0.044546
1983-01-01        3.974       45.653      1.379773      3.821069       0.154235       0.034269
1984-01-01        5.212       47.748      1.650964      3.865937       0.271191       0.044868
```

If you want to go about the chaining method to replicate mutate...across, a combination of assign and pipe with unpacking could help (I feel it reduces readability):

```py
(df.assign(**df.pipe(np.log).add_prefix('l'))
   .pipe(lambda df: df.assign(**df.filter(like='l').sub(df.filter(like='l')
                                  .shift())
                                  .add_prefix('d'))
                             )
)

            jam_cpi_eop  bah_cpi_eop  ljam_cpi_eop  lbah_cpi_eop  dljam_cpi_eop  dlbah_cpi_eop
1980-01-01        3.038       38.714      1.111199      3.656201            NaN            NaN
1981-01-01        3.183       42.193      1.157824      3.742254       0.046625       0.086053
1982-01-01        3.406       44.115      1.225539      3.786800       0.067714       0.044546
1983-01-01        3.974       45.653      1.379773      3.821069       0.154235       0.034269
1984-01-01        5.212       47.748      1.650964      3.865937       0.271191       0.044868
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, there are cleaner ways of doing it for this particular example. In this case I would probably assign the four variables in the same `.assign(lv1=lambda x: np.log(x.v1), lv2=lambda x: np.log(x.v2), dlv1=lambda x: x.lv1 - x.lv1.shift(1), dlv2=lambda x: x.lv2 - x.lv2.shift(1))` or directly `.assign(dlv1=lambda x: np.log(x.v1) - np.log(x.v1.shift(1)) ...`. However, I was interested in knowing if it would be possible to do such a thing that can be useful depending on the situation.